# Django - why am i not authenticated after logging in from Axios/AJAX?

Tags: django, vue.js, axios, django-allauth

I'm building a separated VueJS/Django app where Django will communicate with the Vue frontend using JSON. In order to be able to use the standard session authentication and [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) i will deploy the two apps on the same server and on the same port.

Here is my problem: after i log in from the Vue app using Axios, i don't receive any response but i notice that a session is created on the db, so i'm assuming that i'm getting logged in. But if i try to reach and endpoint that prints `request.user.is_authenticated`i get `False`, and `request.user` returns `Anonymous`, so i'm not logged in anymore. How can i solve this?

Here is my Axios code:

```
bodyFormData.append('login', 'root');
bodyFormData.append('password', 'test');

axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/",
  data: bodyFormData,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
})
.then(function (response) {
  //handle success
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (response) {
  //handle error
  console.log(response);
});
```

I think Django-Allauth supports AJAX authentication on its urls, but i don't understand how to make it return something and how can my Vue app stay authenticated once i submit the Axios form. Any advice is welcome!

Comment: The backend should return a token who frontend should store and send to the backend in each request to authenticate the user. Are you getting the token and saving it?

Comment: The big problem here is that i'm not receiving the token, note that i'm trying to use Session Authentication